# How can I map these classes automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

how can I map Person to Company:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Country { get; set;}
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set;}
}

public class Company
{
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    
}

public class Member
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to do it with auto mapper but I couldn't success .

Comment: Please share the code you tried and did not work.

Comment: The solution is 90% similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74840141) I wrote. 1. Map `Person` to `Member`. 2. Map `Person` to `Company`. Let me know if you have any doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume when mapping `Person` to `Member`, you want the `Person.Name` and `Member.FullName` to be the mapped.

So for that I would do this.

```
CreateMap<Person, Member>()
                .ForMember(
                    x => x.FullName,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FullName)
                    );
```

As for mapping `Person` to `Company`, I really don't understand **why** you would map these two if you already have `Person` and `Member` mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Create a AutomapperProfile Helper class and add all the mapping in there .

```
    public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile 
    {
      public AutomapperProfile()
      {
      CreateMap<Person, Company>();

     }
     }
```

Comment: for this kind of complex models you should customize it because Automapper can't detect it by it own