# AutoMapper - How to map an object to list of objects

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I wanna map `Person` to list of `Client` with AutoMapper:

and this is my models:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Country { get; set;}
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set;}
}

public class Member
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public Member User { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to do it with AutoMapper but I couldn't:

```cs
CreateMap<Person, List<Client>>();
```

Comment: based on your last question you posted, you should try something by yourself https://stackoverflow.com/q/74839555/6527049

Comment: Ok I will try If I found I will reply it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 4 mapping rules:

1. Map `Person` to `Member`.
2. Map `Member` to `Client`.
3. Map `Person` to `Client`.
4. Map `Person` to `List<Client>`.

```cs
CreateMap<Person, Member>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
                                                                  
CreateMap<Member, Client>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.User, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
                                                                  
CreateMap<Person, Client>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dest, ctx) => new Client { User = ctx.Mapper.Map<Member>(src) });
                                                                  
CreateMap<Person, List<Client>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dest, ctx) => new List<Client> { ctx.Mapper.Map<Client>(src) });
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2b5fju)

Answer (score 1):

You can map them using the following code:

```
CreateMap<Person, Client>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.User, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Member { Id = src.Id, FullName = src.Name }));
CreateMap<Person, List<Client>>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => src.Select(x => new Client { User = new Member { Id = x.Id, FullName = x.Name } }).ToList());
```